# Xcode : how to change storyboard load animation left to right

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, storyboard, transition

How i can change storyboard animation from left to right without segue ?

here is the code with which I load the storyboard :

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoadApplicationStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ApplicationController"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are developing iOS 7+ application than custom Transitions are what you need. 
You can give any kind of animation you want to give while going from one view controller to other.

Yes it is not one line code and require some time to learn but it is worth.
You just need to implement two delegate method (ope for Present and one for dismiss) and animation code and you are done.

You can learn that from here :

- [IOS 7 CUSTOM TRANSITIONS (www.thinkandbuild.it/)](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/ios7-custom-transitions/)
- [iOS 7: Custom Transitions (www.doubleencore.com/)](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/)
- [iOS 7 Custom Transitions: An Opportunity to Set Your App Apart From the Competition](http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-transition-ios-7/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of present just push you viewcontroller

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LoadApplicationStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ApplicationController"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: it does not work, the storyboard is not charging when I put pushViewController

Comment: you have to use navigation controller for same controller (self) also,

Answer (score 0):

try this..[here](http://blog.jambura.com/2012/07/05/custom-segue-animation-left-to-right-using-catransition/),in tho post you can made custom Segue Animation left to right Using CATransition

Comment: it does not work, because I use multiple storyboard.